# function doesn't work (doesn't print anything)

Tags: php, function

I have make function but it doesn't want to work , I don't know why or what the wrong because I think all is good

```
function  ifemptySet($who,$set){
   if(empty($who)){
       $who = "$set";   
   }
}


if(isset($_POST['saveinfosite'])){
   $site_name = strip_tags($_POST['site_name']);


   ifemptySet($site_name,"null");


   echo $site_name;




  }
```

When I set the " input " empty , php (echo) doesn't print anything , but when I write something in the "input" , I show only what I have put in the Input

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: The semi-colon after your call to the function means that it doesn't do anything: `ifemptySet($site_name,"null")
   echo $site_name; ` Not does the function actually do anything to return a value

Comment: It not clear what you actually want.Your ifemptySet function does not return anything so if you put it inside if condition it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change your function header to this:

```
function  ifemptySet(&$who,$set){
                   //^See here! Passed by reference 
   if(empty($who)){
       $who = "$set";   
   }
}
```

Also you could do it with return like this:

```
function  ifemptySet($who,$set){
   if(empty($who)){
       return $who = "$set";   
   }
   return $who;
}
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: @user3356666 Your welcome! I updated my answer with a link! You pass the argument by reference!

Comment: @user3356666 Also you can accept & upVote the answer how helped you the most and solved your problem! (See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234 also a 2 min tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Return the value from `ifemptySet()` & assign it to `$site_name`. Can try this

```
function  ifemptySet($who,$set){
    return $who ? $who : $set;
}

if(isset($_POST['saveinfosite'])){
    $site_name = strip_tags($_POST['site_name']);
    $site_name = ifemptySet($site_name, "null");
    echo $site_name;
}
```